# trim certain number of characters from end of javascript string

Tags: javascript, string

What I would like to accomplish is too strip the last certain number of characters from the end of a string in javascript. Lets say I had a string with 'testing this out' and I wanted to strip the last 5 characters from it. How do I do it?

Comment: you want last 5 characters or everything else except last 5 characters.

Comment: thank you post an answer and I'll chose you  as best!

Comment: that was for adeneo.

Comment: I just got a message that says that 'this question already has an answer' - Frustrating. I put in this same key words but I didn't find it. :(